# Changing Jupyter Notebook start location [Win 7 Enterprise]

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to change the default Jupyter Notebook start directory on my Windows 7 Enterprise machine. Other answers have suggested changing the "Start In" field found through Right-click>Properties>Shortcut on the Jupyter program in my Start menu, however this doesn't have any effect. When I change this field to my desired directory and try running the program it still opens in the default directory, when I recheck the "Start In" field it is the same as whatever I had changed it to so it looks like it isn't being changed back by Windows, rather it's being disregarded entirely. For reference the default directory is at P:\ which is not a local directory and is hosted on my company servers, and I am trying to change the Jupyter startup directory to C:.

I'm sure the path is correct - I've tried a few different ones and they are working with autocomplete. I should mention this is a locked down corporate machine and I have to run Jupyter as administrator or else it exits immediately. I do have elevated rights and have checked the user permissions on Jupyter. This is using the Jupyter that comes as default with the current Python 3.5 distribution of Anaconda - I have also tried reinstalling the whole Anaconda package and I'm currently working with a fresh default install.

I am wondering if there is perhaps a way through changing the startup script that is run when you execute the program?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - go to your Anaconda install directory (for me this was C:\Anaconda3) and open the file cwp.py in a text editor. Change the line
`os.chdir(documents_folder)`
to
`os.chdir("C:\\my\\path\\here")`.